# Batch create ASP.net application folders IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, directory

We have a set of about 30-50 users who periodically need an ASP.net (version 4) application directory created for them.

As these numbers grow, manually creating an application directory for each user becomes cumbersome on IIS 7.

Is there a way to create these application folders using a batched/scripted/automated mechanism of some kind?

Ideally we'd like to provide input parameters of a file that contains a batch of application-names, and have the script automatically create the application directories in IIS.

Comment: what about  writing a little exe/service/batch and calling it from c# code?

Comment: Sounds more like a http://serverfault.com/ question.

Comment: Thanks, i went and checked serverfault as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're reinventing [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy).

As to your question, I think it's quite possible (and from what I see, pretty easy as well) to control IIS 7 from C#. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/06/09/iis7-sample-code-for-adding-deleting-a-website-programmatically-c-example.aspx) for more info:

```
ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
Site mySite = serverMgr.Sites.Add("MySiteName", "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot", 8080);
serverMgr.ApplicationPools.Add("MyAppPool");
mySite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "MyAppPool";
mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Enabled = true;
mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Directory = "C:\\inetpub\\customfolder\\site";
serverMgr.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy). It allows non-admin users to deploy web applications to IIS7 servers, even remotely from a command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line tool and script is according to your own needs.

[Getting Started with AppCmd.exe](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)

[Configuring IIS 7 from the command line using Appcmd.exe](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configuring-IIS-7-command-line-Appcmdexe-Part1.html)